# How to sum by agrouping a specific column using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

I`m not able to sum by each group/column.  The idea is to create a new column on this data set with the sum by "store":

```
PNO store   ForecastSUM
17  20054706    WITZ    0.0
8   8007536 WITZ    0.0
2   8007205 WITZ    0.0
12  8601965 WITZ    0.0
5   8007239 WITZ    0.0
14  20054706    ROT 1.0
1   8007205 ROT 7.0
9   8601965 ROT 2.0
6   8007536 ROT 3.0
3   8007239 ROT 2.0
15  20054706    MAR 1.0
7   8007536 MAEG    6.0
10  8601965 MAEG    4.0
4   8007239 MAEG    3.0
0   8007205 MAEG    6.0
13  20054706    BUD 1.0
11  8601965 AYC 0.0
16  20054706    AYC 0.0
```

I am trying to apply this code:

```
copiedDataWHSE['sumWHSE'] = copiedDataWHSE.groupby(['ForecastSUM']).agg({'ForecastSUM': "sum"})
```

and the result I am getting is:

```
PNO store   ForecastSUM sumWHSE
17  20054706    WITZ    0.0 NaN
8   8007536 WITZ    0.0 NaN
2   8007205 WITZ    0.0 4.0
12  8601965 WITZ    0.0 NaN
5   8007239 WITZ    0.0 NaN
14  20054706    ROT 1.0 NaN
1   8007205 ROT 7.0 3.0
9   8601965 ROT 2.0 NaN
6   8007536 ROT 3.0 12.0
3   8007239 ROT 2.0 6.0
15  20054706    MAR 1.0 NaN
7   8007536 MAEG    6.0 7.0
10  8601965 MAEG    4.0 NaN
4   8007239 MAEG    3.0 4.0
0   8007205 MAEG    6.0 0.0
13  20054706    BUD 1.0 NaN
11  8601965 AYC 0.0 NaN
16  20054706    AYC 0.0 NaN
```

Which is wrong, since I would like to have as example, once the store is ROT, the sumWHSE column should receive 19.

Comment: why are you grouping on ForecastSum, if you are going to aggregate on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sammywemmy mentions, you need to group on `store`, not on `ForecastSUM`:

```
store_groupby = df.groupby(['store']).agg({'ForecastSUM': "sum"})
```

However, since it's a groupby of length `6`, you can't assign it back to the dataframe as a new column.

What I would do is turn the groupby into a dictionary, then [`assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) it to a new column with a lambda function.

```
store_groupby_dict = store_groupby.to_dict()

df = df.assign(store_total = lambda x: store_groupby_dict[x.store])
```

Doing the same thing with [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply) makes it a little more readable:

```
df['store_total'] = df.store.apply(lambda x: store_groupby_dict[x])
```

Comment: Once I apply the df['store_total'] = df.store.apply(lambda x: store_groupby_dict[x]), the follow erroe happens:

Comment: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-130-a19458ebf745> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 copiedDataWHSE['store_total'] = copiedDataWHSE['store'].apply(lambda x: store_groupby_dict[x])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3192             else:
   3193                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3194                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)

Comment: 3195 
   3196         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-130-a19458ebf745> in <lambda>(x)
      1 
----> 2 copiedDataWHSE['store_total'] = copiedDataWHSE['store'].apply(lambda x: store_groupby_dict[x])

KeyError: 'WITZ'

Comment: Is is not recognizing the WITZ as a key. What should I do ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12399409/k-n-c could you help me here ?

Comment: You'll need to share a [example] of your code as an edit to your question for us to help you.